# eval is giving error in shell script

Tags: xml, shell, unix, eval, ksh

My XML file(in.xml) is like :

```
 <Users>
  <Host>
   <hostAddress>180.144.226.47</hostAddress>
   <userName>pwdfe</userName>
   <password>hjitre</password>
   <instanceCount>2</instanceCount>
   </Host>
 <Host>
  <hostAddress>180.144.226.87</hostAddress>
   <userName>trrrer</userName>
   <password>jhjjhhj</password>
   <instanceCount>3</instanceCount>
  </Host>
 </Users>
```

And my shell script is :

```
  #!/bin/ksh
  for tag in hostAddress userName password instanceCount
  do
   OUT=`grep  $tag in.xml | tr -d '\t' | sed 's/^<.*>\([^<].*\)<.*>$/\1/' `
   # This is what I call the eval_trick, difficult to explain in words.
   eval ${tag}=`echo -ne \""${OUT}"\"`
  done

  # So let's stuff the obtained results into 4 different Arrays

  H_ARRAY=( `echo ${hostAddress}` )
  U_ARRAY=( `echo ${userName}` )
  P_ARRAY=( `echo ${password}` )
  I_ARRAY=( `echo ${instanceCount}` )

  # Ok, time to announce success, let's printout each of the arrays

  echo ${H_ARRAY[@]}
  echo ${U_ARRAY[@]}
  echo ${P_ARRAY[@]}
  echo ${I_ARRAY[@]}
```

While executing the script, I am getting this error :
       eval[1]: -ne: not found[No such file or directory]

Could anyone please help me in resolving the issue?

Comment: `echo` is a shell built in as well as a binary. Try `/bin/echo`

Comment: i tried but the same error...

Comment: Why does this code need to use `eval` at all?

Comment: BashFAQ #6 -- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006 -- shows you how to do indirect assignments without needing `eval`. Its answers _do_ cover ksh (if you're using ksh93, then you have a particularly wide range of available options, extending even to namevars -- which bash didn't have until its 4.3 release).

Comment: By the way -- take a look at what happens to `P_ARRAY` when a password contains a `*` surrounded by whitespace.

Comment: Also, `echo ${some_array[@]}` is a very poor practice, as it gives you no way to distinguish between `"foo bar" baz` and `foo "bar baz"`. I'd consider instead: `printf 'Host: %s\n' "${H_ARRAY[@]}"`; that way you know how many separate hosts you're parsing into, and you don't expand globs (changing, for instance, `*.txt` into a list of text files in the directory where the script runs).

Comment: Also -- all-uppercase names are conventional for environment variables and builtins. Consider using lowercase names for non-exported variables local to your script; that way you don't risk namespace collisions with variable names in the former categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some general issues:

- [Use `$(command)` rather than `` `command` ``.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)
- Rather than using `eval` ([which is evil](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)), just create a function to extract an arbitrary element (essentially just your `grep` line) and run that four times.
- To [add items to an array](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays) (rather than replacing the contents like you do) you can use `array_variable+=(array_element)`
- [Use More Quotes™](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)

Answer (score 1):

If you're really certain you need the effects of `echo -e`, and are running ksh93 or mksh, you can use a nameref to perform the indirect assignment, avoiding the need for `eval`:

```
typeset -n ref="$tag"
ref=$(echo -ne "$OUT")
```

If you were using bash, I would suggest the following (which also performs `echo -e`'s backslash-sequence expansion):

```
printf -v "$tag" %b "$OUT"
```